# Make execute commands on folder context multiple times

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I'm having a `makefile` which under `proj` root dir.

Folder `proj` is the main folder and there is folders such as `ws-led` or `tools-ext` etc under it which contains docker files.
In addition, there is also `Makefile` which is under the root that needs to run all the commands.

This is the folder structure

```
proj
 - ws-led
  — Dockerfile
 - tools-ext
  — Dockerfile    
- Makefile
```

What I need is to `cd` to each of the folders under the rot (we have many more) and run:

`docker build <folder name> .`

**Example:** ( exactly like running the following command manually )

```
cd ws-led
docker build -t ws-led .

cd tools-ext
docker build -t tools-ext .
```

I try with the following (maybe instead of repo param I get run on all the folders in the same level of the Makefile )

Like (CURDIR) …

```
all: pre docker-build
.PHONY: pre docker-build

repos := ws-led tools-ext

pre:
    $(patsubst %,docker-build,$(repos))

docker-build:pre
    cd $*; docker build -t $* . >&2 | tee docker-build
```

while using this im getting an error:

```
invalid argument "." for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
```

Any idea what is wrong here ? or i could do it better?

As I've many repos/folders I want to use `make` to handle it

Comment: You need to be careful with how make eats quotes and special characters before it execs the bash subshell.   I forget all the rules.....

Comment: $s are magic to Make; so $? probably needs to be $$?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it.

You could use a bash for loop:

```
docker-build:
    for dir in $(repos); do cd $$dir; docker build -t $$dir . >&2 | tee docker-build; done
```

Or use a pattern rule (or in this case a static pattern rule):

```
REPO_BUILDS := $(addsuffix -build, $(repos))

docker-build: $(REPO_BUILDS)

.PHONY: $(REPO_BUILDS)
$(REPO_BUILDS): %-build:
    cd $*; docker build -t $* . >&2 | tee docker-build
```